# Por que no puedo recuperar un registro con el parametro en la ruta Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, router

Me pasa algo raro con los modelos de laravel.

Estoy buscando a un usuario por ruta es decir:

Cuando mi usuario entra a una liga de esta forma

> api.smartsolutions.xyz/traker/link/15e2387d-1b73-4276-aeb0-494c8a7515e9

> api.smartsolutions.xyz/traker/link/{user}

Quiero recuperar al usuario apartir de ese guid.

```
 public function link(Email $user){
    return response()->json(['id'=> $user]);
 }

// pero no recupera al usuario esta es su respuesta.
{
  "user": [
    
  ]
}
```

Creo que todo es correcto

en el modelo configure la llave por la que debe buscar.

```
public function getRouteKeyName(){       
    return 'guid';
}
```

Y por si tienen duda de como hice la ruta:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'traker'], function($page){
  $page->get('/link/{user}', 'TrakerEmail\App\Http\Controllers\TrakerController@link');
});
```

Sin embargo cuando busco al usuario con el modelo si lo encuentro.

```
    public function link($user){
        dd(Email::where('guid', $user)->first());
    }

// esta es la respuesta

    "id" => 2
    "guid" => "15e2387d-1b73-4276-aeb0-494c8a7515e9"
    "email_list_id" => 1
    "email" => "test_de_prueba@gmail.com"
    "name" => "test de pueba"
    "lastname" => "test de prueba"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2020-07-24 01:24:58"
    "updated_at" => "2020-07-24 01:24:58"
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisa y tu web.php

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'traker'], function($page){
$page->get('/link/{user}', 'TrakerEmail\App\Http\Controllers\TrakerController@link');
});
```

Deberia ser.

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'traker'], function($page){
$page->get('/link/{user}', 'TrakerController@link');
});
```

Comment: Ammm eso es correcto cuando el provider tiene configurado el path de los controladores. En este caso estoy haciendo un paquete por lo que el path de estos controladores es diferente al de la aplicación. Encontré en la documentación de laravel  que el RouteServiceProvider extiende deIlluminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider  y no de ServiceProvider. 

Hice un segundo proveedor extendiéndolo de este provider y funcionan ya la inyección de los modelos en las rutas.